# MySQL SUM() Operation

Tags: mysql

```
Column A    Column B
'X'           11    
'Y'           42    
'X'           72    
'X'           14    
'Z'           51
```

formula=(x) + (z/2)

I want to sum this data in MySQL. Thanks.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? Right now I can't really make sense out of your question ...

Comment: Could you explain what your formula is supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE ColA
            WHEN 'X' THEN ColB
            WHEN 'Z' THEN ColB/2
           END) AS formula
FROM YourTable
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ba13/2)